# Cassandra Java driver error "IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported error code: 5888"

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

i try to use cassandra as db recently
my cluster version is 4.0.3
and driver version is datastax.oss:java-driver-core:4.13.0

some times my write query occur this error

```
com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.connection.ClosedConnectionException: Unexpected error on channel
Caused by: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported error code: 5888
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported error code: 5888
```

only clue i have is this kind of error is caused by not handled error 5888
from response of cluster

but i can not find what it means...

if any one know about this? or experienced similar situation?

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Please provide (1) the full error message, (2) the full stack trace, (3) an example of your write query, and (4) table schema. Cheers!

Comment: it is just simple write query. 
not every request is failed but sometimes same query make error...
and all error stack trace is above.

Comment: It's missing the full error message which is the line BEFORE the stack trace. And it also looks like the stack trace is truncated. There should be more.

Comment: i upgrade my driver version to 4.14.1 and error is change to com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.servererrors.CASWriteUnknownException: CAS operation result is unknown - proposal was not accepted by a quorum. (1 / 2)

Answer (score 0):

With insufficient information provided, it seems to me that the traffic between the app and the Cassandra cluster is getting interrupted, possibly even packets getting dropped.

When Netty (used by the driver) tries to decode the message here:

```
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:98)
```

it fails to decode it and throws an exception.

I've seen similar instances in the past (although not identical to this stack trace) where this happened as a result of packets getting dropped so one of the frames in the message is missing and the driver received a frame whose contents it didn't recognise.

Without the additional information I requested, it would be difficult to diagnose this issue. Cheers!

Comment: thanks for reply even though lack of information.

Comment: and also i debug code line that you mentioned!
recent version of driver handle error code 5888. finally i knew what is issue..